# Attempting to Compile and Execute Old Fortran 77 Code Using GFortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

The code that I am working with was originally written in FORTRAN 77. I am hesitant to update all of the files to a more modern standard since there are multiple files thousands of lines long that rely on obsolete functions.

During compilation, I get a few type mismatch arguments, most of which are taken care of with -freal-4-real-8, but I am unsure if that is a permanent solution.

I currently use the following flags to compile all of the object files which are then compiled into the final executable: -ff2c -std=legacy -freal-4-real-8

The file in which the error occurs is compiled without the -freal flag because it uses a function that requires a real(4) variable.

The current error I am getting upon running the executable is:
    At line 2680 of file twopt.f
    Fortran runtime error: Assigned label is not a target label

The subroutine in which the error occurs takes in REENT as a logical parameter. ROUTE is later declared as an integer but is not assigned any value which I think might be the reason behind the problem. I used print statements to check its value before the error occurs, and REENT is true, and ROUTE is 0.

Code at lines 2678-2681:

IF (REENT) THEN
    REENT = .FALSE.
    GO TO ROUTE
END IF

In the subroutine there is no statement label with the value of 0 which also might contribute to the error. Again, I am hesitant to edit the code too much since it supposedly worked as intended back in the ‘90s. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have an assigned go to statement then there must be a corresponding label, and `0` wasn't a valid statement label in F77 (and still isn't).  Without more detail then I'm afraid there's not much more to say.

Comment: If you're compiling only Fortran and linking this into an executable, you likely do not need -ff2c.

Comment: Find out where Is ROUTE assigned in the subroutine/function.  Is that piece of code ever executed?  If it is, is there an array before it - it might be exceeding its bounds.